# Stopping a looping script from returning duplicate entries

Tags: python, xml, loops, python-2.7, duplicates

I have code which currently prints out data for each user from an XML file (obtained from a website) the XML updates as more users interact with it throughout the day. I currently have my code looping to download this data every 5 minutes.

Every time the code is ran it generates a list of users and their statistics, 
 first 5 mins  it prints users: a,b,c

second 5 mins it prints users : a,b,c,d,e

third 5 mins it prints users : a,b,c,d,e,f,g

What i need the code to do it to print first 5 mins:  a,b,c second 5 mins: d,e third 5 mins: f,g

Some how recognising that some of the users have already been used. Each user does have a unique user id which i guess could be matched?

I enclose an example of my code, in case that helps.

```
import mechanize
import urllib
import json
import re
import random
import datetime
from sched import scheduler
from time import time, sleep

######Code to loop the script and set up scheduling time

s = scheduler(time, sleep)
random.seed()

def run_periodically(start, end, interval, func):
    event_time = start
    while event_time < end:
        s.enterabs(event_time, 0, func, ())
        event_time += interval + random.randrange(-5, 45)
    s.run()


###### Code to get the data required from the URL desired
def getData():  
    post_url = "URL OF INTEREST"
    browser = mechanize.Browser()
    browser.set_handle_robots(False)
    browser.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]

######These are the parameters you've got from checking with the aforementioned tools
    parameters = {'page' : '1',
              'rp' : '250',
              'sortname' : 'roi',
              'sortorder' : 'desc'
             }
#####Encode the parameters
    data = urllib.urlencode(parameters)
    trans_array = browser.open(post_url,data).read().decode('UTF-8')

    xmlload1 = json.loads(trans_array)
    pattern1 = re.compile('>&nbsp;&nbsp;(.*)<')
    pattern2 = re.compile('/control/profile/view/(.*)\' title=')
    pattern3 = re.compile('<span style=\'font-size:12px;\'>(.*)<\/span>')


#########################################################################
##### The request sent from here all the way down including comments#####
#########################################################################


##### Making the code identify each row, removing the need to numerically quantify the     number of rows in the xmlfile,
##### thus making number of rows dynamic (change as the list grows, required for looping function to work un interupted)

    for row in xmlload1['rows']:
        cell = row["cell"]

##### defining the Keys (key is the area from which data is pulled in the XML) for use in the pattern finding/regex

        user_delimiter = cell['username']
        selection_delimiter = cell['race_horse']


        if strikeratecalc2 < 12 : continue;

##### REMAINDER OF THE REGEX DELMITATIONS
        username_delimiter_results = re.findall(pattern1, user_delimiter)[0]
        userid_delimiter_results = (re.findall(pattern2, user_delimiter)[0])
        user_selection = re.findall(pattern3, selection_delimiter)[0]



##### Printing the results of the code at hand

        print "user id = ",userid_delimiter_results
        print "username = ",username_delimiter_results
        print "user selection = ",user_selection
        print ""





    getData()


    run_periodically(time()+5, time()+1000000, 3000, getData)
```

Please be nice with comments, I have been coding for a cumulative 11 days now, so also excuse any major errors in the code I am using, although it is working so far.

Kind regards

AEA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you could simply store the unique id's somewhere (like a file or db - `Redis` is my absolute favorite) and then check them.

For storing with `Redis`, you could do something like this:

```
# redis
import redis
pwd = 'l33t'
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=1, password=pwd)  

# set id's
r.sadd('user_ids', unique_id) # this is a set, with no duplicates

# check for existing id's
r.sismember('user_ids', unique_id) # returns 1 or 0
```

See http://redis.io/commands#set and https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py.  You need both `Redis` and `redis-py`, takes two minutes to install.

Comment: I have another project coming up which will involve the use of a database so if i start using one i want it to be the easiest one tbh. According to this thread mongodb is easier to code? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400163/when-to-redis-when-to-mongodb  (I literally started coding 11 days ago, started from "hello world"!) What do you reckon reddis or mongo?

Comment: I've been through both of them actually - and I recommend Redis by a long shot.  It's insanely fast and very easy to use.  I use it for everything now, and I'm a relative n00b.