# Need(easy to use) database for analysis data

Tags: python, database, analytics, nosql

I'm looking for the database (python api) for tasks described below.

There is an increasing amount of data. In the initial period of accumulation of the data will be simple analysis that can be done with simple sql queries. But in the future it is planned to extract data from more complex queries, finding complex relationships. Requires initially choose a data storage system, which in future will allow to analyze this database different, things get complicated ( as you explore topics and skills development ) tools.

Example:

First, there is only data on buckwheat and rice. Required to compare sales growth during the month. No problem - two sql query by product name, limited sampling time (month). Drawn graphs, clearly see what is what. There are more kinds of goods. Now it took to learn how to depend on sales growth Soya sauce from rice sales growth. This is somehow possible from using sql query. And now we have 5000 names in the database and requires using some algorithms (eg neural networks) seek any dependencies in the database automatically. 
That is, start with simple, needs grow, become more complicated tools.
What db suited to increasing requirements, being a simple enough for use in the beginning?
Is Redis, for example?

I would have been very useful to know that in my question incorrectly. I am totally new to this subject. it tells me what to look

Comment: MongoDB should be enough. It's being actively used for analysis ad monitoring.

Comment: Except you can't run SQL queries directly against a MongoDB database, and it's also not relational.

Comment: sql queries is not a requirement. it is for example in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, MongoDB is suited for that. If you had millions of entries with multiple relations, SQL would be ahead. But for some thousands of entries a document-based DB does the job. As a benefit you don't have to care about the structure of your DB before you create it and are able to easily change it later. Take a look at the [PyMongo Tutorial](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html).

Comment: what you think about Redis?

Comment: I haven't used it myself, but it seems to be VERY fast, though maybe a little more difficult than MongoDB, a short comparison between both is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400163/when-to-redis-when-to-mongodb. Hope it helps! CU

Comment: it says here http://blog.mongodb.org/post/137788967/32-bit-limitations   32-bit MongoDB processes are limited to about 2 gb of data. Does this mean that I can not analyze the data size of 25GB or more with mongo? Or is there a possibility of how to divide it into parts?