# How to use Redis and MongoDb together

Tags: mongodb, redis, architecture

I should build a web application to track users activities and I have some issues to understand how can use Redis for tracking online users activities and Mongo to store that data for analyzing it.

I could use just Mongo but I'm worried about the fact I have a lot of invocations to follow what a user is doing. So I was thinking to write on Redis the online data and put in Mongo when they become old. I mean old when the data is meaningless for being online.

I thought about one gateway between Mongo and Redis, so could be RabbitMQ?.

Any suggestions?
I should use just Mongo?

Just an example of code I wrote:

Front-end (Angular application / Socket.io):

```
setInterval(function () {
   socket.emit('visitor-data', {
       referringSite: document.referrer,
       browser: navigator.sayswho,
       os: navigator.platform,
       page: location.pathname
   });
}, 3000);
```

Back-end ( Node.js/ Socket.io)

```
socket.on('visitor-data', function(data) {
    visitorsData[socket.id] = data;
);
```

VisitorsData is a just in an array, but I should build a scalable application, so I can't store data anymore in this way.

Then I have some functions like this for computing the data:

```
function computeRefererCounts() {

    var referrerCounts = {};
    for (var key in visitorsData) {
         var referringSite = visitorsData[key].referringSite || '(direct)';
         if (referringSite in referrerCounts) {
             referrerCounts[referringSite]++;
         } else {
             referrerCounts[referringSite] = 1;
         }
    }
    return referrerCounts;
}
```

Just some numbers:
I estimated something like :

1. 1 million users for day
2. 15 million activities for day.

Comment: I chose Redis because I think is faster than mongo for my goal.

Comment: @cirosomma, show us what work have you done and what programming issues you are facing. SO discourages opinionated question.

Comment: Read this post, it will give u a lot of inputs on deciding between Redis/MongoDb - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400163/when-to-redis-when-to-mongodb. In my opinion, having both DB's is not a good option

Comment: @hitesh yes. I could perform operations.

Comment: @Saleem I'll edit with details.

Comment: @hitesh Yes. I'll use someing like that.