# Best solution for dynamic spatial data

Tags: azure, dynamic, storage, spatial

I'm trying to find the best solution for storing **dynamic spatial data**. I wonder if any of Microsoft's Azure solutions could work. Azure Table Storage would let me create a lot of custom and dynamic structures stored on fast **SSD disks**.

Because of **data's dynamic nature**, common **indexing seems useless**. I would also like to create a lot of table-like structures so the whole **architecture cannot be static**. Using Azure Table Storage I would dynamically create a table based on country, city, etc sorted by latitude or longitude.

I would appreciate any clue.

Comment: What, exactly, is "dynamic spatial data?" Also: Why would indexing be "useless"? Many apps run with schema-free approaches (just look at document stores in Azure's Cosmos DB), and indexes are still a key part of that storage service.

Comment: Also, there are built-in spatial features in several of Azure's built-in data services, and they are also available to many database engines you can install yourself to VM's. Which one you choose is really up to you; the choices and decisions are quite broad. This question, as written, is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Dynamic means that record is in at 12:00:05 and could be out (or ignored) 20-25 seconds later. For example user taps 'I'm here' - 20-25 secs later he taps 'Cancel my current location' so the record is no longer considered in terms of nearest neighbour search process.

Answer (score 0):

[Azure Table Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables) has mostly been replaced by [Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/introduction).

At the time of writing the Table Storage page even says:

> The content in this article applies to the original basic Azure Table storage. However, there is now a premium offering for Azure Table storage in public preview that offers throughput-optimized tables, global distribution, and automatic secondary indexes. To learn more and try out the new premium experience, please check out Azure Cosmos DB: Table API.

You can use Cosmos DB via the [`Table` API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-introduction), but you'll probably find the [`Document DB` API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-introduction) to be more powerful.

`Documents` are ["schema-free"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117372/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-a-schema-free-database-like-mongodb-compared-to). You can just throw your documents in to a collection, and then you can query against them.

You can create documents which have [geo-spatial properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/geospatial) which are [indexed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/geospatial#indexing) automatically.

Then you can perform geo-spatial [queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/geospatial#querying-spatial-types)  against those properties.

For example you might give each of your documents a point, and then create a query to select all documents that are inside of a polygon.

Or maybe you want to find out how far away each document is from a given point.